# AJAX - can another function execute in the middle of success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a question that should be better explained by code than words:

```
function insertElement(){
    var element = jQuery('<div class="element"></div>');
    jQuery('body').append(element);
    return element;
}

jQuery('body').on('click', '.element', function(){
    jQuery(this).remove();
});

var element = insertElement();
var elementHasContent = false;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajax_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'action': 'some_function',
        'parameters': {'some_parameter': 'some_value'}
    },
    global: false,
    success: function(output){

        // Break if the element doesn't exist anymore.
        if(jQuery(element).length == 0){
            return;
        }

        /* Question: Is it possible that user clicked the element right
         * at this moment (after my check and before elementHasContent
         * variable is set to true?
         */

        var elementHasContent = true;
        jQuery(element).html(output);
    }
});
```

The question is in the comment. Basically I'm wondering if removal of the element can happen while some other part of the code is in the middle of its execution. Please ask me questions if something is unclear.

Comment: "jQuery" equels to $ mark. To reduce and quick coding use $ instead of "jQuery" word. Ex $('body').append(element);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will not occur.

Javascript is not multi-threaded. It is event driven. That means each event (in this case mouse click or Ajax response) will complete before the next one executes. Individual events do not get interrupted partway through.

Think of the async Ajax call as just generating an event, in response to the server's response. It gets queued up alongside the user mouse-click. Whichever got their first gets executed first.

*This is all a good thing as multi-threaded programming would make JavaScript far more complicated than it needs to be :)*

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer yet and accept it but that's exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you.